# tcpdump/Wireshark on restricted virtual server

Tags: linux, vps, tcpdump

When I try to dump some traffic on my vserver's network interface, I get an error that I'm not allowed to do that:

```
# tcpdump -p -i eth0
tcpdump: eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted)
```

I guess the problem is that my server provider seems to use a virtualization solution with shared Linux kernel (uname returns "2.6.33.7-vs2.3.0.36.30.4-netcup" as version).

Any way that allows me to dump outgoing traffic from a single process?

Comment: Any "real" hypervisor-powered VPS would allow this, so I'm guessing that you're on a pseudo VPS, probably running under OpenVZ or the like, which doesn't give users access to this type of device.

Comment: @ErikA: Yes, that's what I meant. As I found out now, the provider uses Linux-VServer for virtualization. (Did I use the wrong term with "VPS"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `strace` command to trace the system calls your application is making.  Something like this:

```
strace -o trace -e trace=read,write -s 8192 /path/to/my/command
```

This will launch `/path/to/my/command` under control of `strace`.  It will log all `read` and `write` system calls (so not just network traffic, but any other i/o) to a file called `trace`.  It will log up to 8192 characters for each read/write call.

This may or may not be helpful for your current situation.

Comment: That's a nice solution, and I can simply filter it with `grep`. As a hint: One may also want to add "send,sendto" to the tracing (for outgoing packets).